# Steepest direction on a plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, solid-geometry

How do you find the steepest direction on a plane P wrt to the x-y plane? Isn't this direction unique? The question says that the steepest direction makes the largest acute angle with the x-y plane?

So if you have a plane P that contains the vectors u = (3, −1, −2) and
v = (−1, 0, 5). What is the steepest direction on P wrt x-y plane? Is this an angle or another vector? I am confused.

Comment: Unless the plane you are talking about contains the origin or another point, you don't have a plane. You need three points to define a plane.

Comment: Note that the PLANE CONTAINS THE VECTORS - which means that for the purpose of the question the origin could be included since the discussion is really of all the family of planes that contains such vectors and any you pick will do.

Comment: Use the product to create a vector perpendicular to the two and than find the angel between this vector and the XY plane. Subtract from ${\pi}/2$

Answer (score 0):

Without proof, rather based on intuition: if your two vectors are linearly independent and so define the plane, you can calculate the plane normal n = u cross v. From the xy-plane (eg. u_0 = (1, 0, 0), v_0 = (0, 1, 0)) you get the plane normal n_0 = (0, 0, 1). Now, you can build the cross product of the 2 normals, n_0 cross n, which yields an vector w orthogonal to them, which depends on their angle. To turn this vector w into the plane in the direction of the steepest decent you build the cross product with the plane normal and receive the vector of steepest decent g = w cross n.
Your data yield:

n = (-5, -13, -1)

w = (13, -5, 0)

g = (5, 13, -194) or norm(g) = (0.026, 0.067, -0.997)

[normalized vectors u(green), v(orange), g(black)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I37hw.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).